# How do I properly rewrite my URLs to give a proper 404 page?

Tags: .htaccess

I am having an issue with my current .htaccess mod_rewrite configuration.

Here is my current code:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\/$ /game.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\/$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\/$ /category.php?cid=$1&page=$2&title=$3 [L]
```

The above code properly rewrites my URLs. However, whenever I type in into my browser a directory that doesn't exist, like, http://www.example.com/non-existent-directory/ my homepage shows up rather than the 404 page I have set up.

Another note, the trailing slash seems to make all the difference. If I remove the trailing slash from the URL, i.e., http://www.example.com/non-existent-directory the 404 page properly shows up. If I add it, my homepage appears and not the 404 page as it should.

Does anyone know what I need to do to get my URL to rewrite, but also show the 404 page when I type a non-existent directory?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

it's the `ErrorDocument` direction; while one can strip the trailing slash, as well:

```
# Rewrites
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # remove trailing slash
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]

    ...

</IfModule>

# HTTP Errors
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?controller=frontend&method=error&id=404
```